# Changing requirements as you go

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that in a lot of openended puzzles, the requirements are changed to disallow certain solutions. Is there an official policy on this? For example, in [Scramble Sentences](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22019/longest-scramble-sentence) I made three valid answers and each time the rules were changed to prevent my answers from being allowed.

Comment: While I do agree the answers were technically correct, I feel Puzzling has grown beyond the 'cheap' or 'out of the box' answers to exploit fairly obvious loopholes in the questions asked. The reason it does still happen, is often in an attempt to achieve more reputation, or in some cases, 'smartass'-behaviour. I could see how the OP would perceive certain answers to certain questions as unfit, or even a mockery of the OP. In such cases, if answers are given rather then a vote to put on hold, I personally think the alterations as shown in the example should be allowed.

Comment: That said, this was by no means a personal judgement on either the OP of the puzzle, the poster of this question, or the specifics of the question. In general I agree with Emrakul that we (as a community) need to lean towards putting on hold rather then striving to rack up reputation points.

Comment: @TimCouwelier: I agree completely. My answer to that question was not meant to be a "smartass" answer - in that case, though, the question's premise was beyond salvaging (IMO at least)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a sign that the question should be put on hold as "unclear what you're asking"/"too broad" until the author can sort out the details (with the help of the community) as to what answers are and are not valid. After those details have been sorted out, the question can be reopened; answers that used to answer the question but don't any longer should probably be deleted as well.

Patching up the question to exclude answers that have already been posted *does* disrupt the existing answers, and it puts a stumbling block in front of people who are thinking of answering the question in the future. It's better to put questions where the requirements are unclear on hold until the question's loopholes have been sufficiently closed.